# VF page show last record instead of selected one

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects, standardcontroller

I have standard object tab and added object button to VisualForce page on it.
The VF have very simple code:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Contract" recordSetVar="Contract">
     <apex:pageBlock title="The id of the Contract Standard object">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contract}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.Status}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.ContractNumber}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:page>
```

But when i click the button the VF page display always the last record instead of selected one:
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to make the VF page display selected record (or records, could be more than one selected) instead of last one?

Comment: What happens if you use `{!selected}` for the value parameter of the pageBlockTable? It's been years since I played with this stuff but when you use a StandardSetController in Apex it has a separate list of selected records, seems odd that you've only got one and the wrong one though.

Comment: Thanks Matt, {!selected} is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StandardSetControllers` maintain two lists of records, one of which is the set of selected records, and this information can come from a list view as you desire.

Swapping out the name of your `recordSetVar` in the page block table for `{!selected}` (which calls the Apex method `getSelected()` from the `StandardSetController` class in the background) should do the trick:

```
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="a">
       <apex:column value="{!a.Status}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!a.ContractNumber}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
```